# Copy-transform a numeric field in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I have a dynamic numeric multivalued field in my solr schema -

```
<dynamicField name="*_nm" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="false"/>
```

I'd like to run a function score on said field -

```
_val_:"if(exists(features.width_nm),mul(exp(div(pow(max(0,sub(abs(sub(features.width_nm,12.00000)),0.00000)),2),-51.93702)),10.00000),0.000000)"
```

but function queries on multivalued fields aren't properly supported in my version of Solr (5.2.1). Trying the above gives the error -

> "can not use FieldCache on multivalued field"

My current work-around for this is during indexing to create another field, numeric single-valued, which contains a "reduced" form of the multivalues.

Currently I do this in Java code.
**Is there any way for me to do this directly in Solr? for example using a "copy-field"?**

Just for completeness - In solr 6.3 I am able to calculate a function-score on a multivalued field by using the field function with a min/max parameter described [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html#field).

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the "reduced form"? You can use arbitrary javascript in a update chain with a scriptprocessor when indexing, so you should be able to add any transformation you need that way. copyField happens before any processing takes place, so it can't add transformations by itself.

Comment: The "reduce" is usually just an average of all values.
That's sounds great, I'll look into it!